# How to view a visio document inside a form in MS-Access app?

Tags: ms-access, visio

I want only to able to view a visio document content from inside a MS-Access' form. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visio Viewer Control. Drop it on your access form and specify the path to the Visio file to render. Check out more on Viewer Control in MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768041.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @Nikolay. I followed the first option of the site guide and added the visio library into VBA. But could't find the "Remove information about unused ActiveX controls" and uncheck it.

I get the error (translated): "The type defined by the user was not defined"

Comment: You can ignore that item about "unused activex controls", it was about Visual Basic 6.0, which is long dead. Normally you should have this control in the toolbox, and just drop it on the form. If you don't have it in the toolbox, right click and select "add activex control.."

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the error "The type defined by the user was not defined".

Answer (score 0):

From the VBA window in your database, click on Tools, References. Scroll down the list until you see "Microsoft Visio Viewer 16.0 Type Library". Assuming you have installed the application first, that is.  It is available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51188
Note this is visio viewer, not visio.